# Error while Reading and Parsing JSONArray String from SharedPreference

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, jsonexception

I have stored `JSONArray` as a String in `SharedPreference`.This is my `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        try {
            info.put("name", full_name);
            info.put("phone", foodie_contact);                    
            info.put("no_people", no_peoples);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I am storing  this Object in Array and array in SharedPreference as

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
            array.put(info.toString());
            alert.noInternetAlert(getActivity());
            edit=addqueuetemp.edit();
            edit.putString("queuedata",array.toString());
            edit.apply();
```

Now, I am taking JSONArray from SharedPreference and parse it as

```
try {
                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(addqueuetemp.getString("queuedata","[]"));
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i+1);
                    Log.i("OBJECT",obj.toString());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The format of String I am getting after reading from Preference is
 `["{\"name\":\"payal\",\"phone\":\"7427427427\",\"no_people\":\"5\"}"]`
I am getting Error as
`Value {"name":"payal","phone":"7427427427","no_people":"5"} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`
How to resolve this ? where is the actual problem ?

Comment: Use `Gson` to parse **string** to and from `JSON`. issue is direct parsing to **string from JSON** appends additional quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a `String` into your `JSONArray`, not the `JSONObject`:

```
array.put(info.toString());
```

That's why you can only get it as a `String`.

Remove that `.toString()`, and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
array.put(info.toString());
```

to

```
array.put(info);
```

As you want to save object in array , but actually you're saving `String` in array

Answer (score 0):

To convert your string to json array you need to use follow code.

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JSONArray jo = (JSONArray)jsonParser.parse(json);
```